# Remove duplicate fields in a given column (after ID check)

Tags: text-processing

I'd like to remove from a given column ($2 in the example) the duplicate fields (comma separated), but only if the ID column ($1 in the example) is the same.

Input:

```
A    1,2,3,4
A    8,9,10,11
A    2,3,4,11,12
B    4,5,6,7
B    6,8,9,10
```

Expected output:

```
A    1,2,3,4
A    8,9,10,11
A    12
B    4,5,6,7
B    8,9,10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is easy enough in `awk` using an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays), [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-split_0028_0029-function), and a regular [loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array):

```
{
    split($2, elements, ",")
    out = ""
    for (i in elements) {
        el = elements[i]
        key = $1 " " el
        if (!(key in used)) {
            out = out el ","
        }
        used[key] = 1
    }
    sub(/,$/, "", out)
    $2 = out
}
1
```

For each line, we split the second column by commas and save the bits into an array `elements`. We then build up the new value for that column with a loop, checking whether we've seen the value before or not.

We're keeping the set of values we've already seen in the (associative) array `used`. We construct a string `key` containing both the value of the first column and the value from the second we're currently looking at. If `key` is in `used`, we've seen this one before for this ID and shouldn't put it in the output; otherwise, it's new, and we concatenate the value to `out`. So that we don't use it again, we store `key` (which will be something like "`A 3`") into our set of seen elements.

Finally, we put the constructed list back into the second column. This is essentially the approach you'd take in any other language.

Put the code above into a file and run it with `awk -f`, or single-quote all of it as an argument on the command line.

Comment: You may want to use a space instead of `_` as that's guaranteed not to be found in the fields. Note that it doesn't preserve the spacing of the fields.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -lpe 's/(\S+)\s+\K\S+/join ",", grep {!$seen{$1}->{$_}++} split ",", $&/e'
```